# How do I find out if a column is required or nullable using a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to know if it's possible to know if a Column is "Required" or "Nullable". I can't find any information about this. Is there any Stored Procedure that let's me know if the column is a required field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle**

```
SELECT nullable
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'TableName'
    AND column_name = 'ColumnName';
```

---

**SQL-SERVER**

```
SELECT is_nullable 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = object_id('TableName') 
    AND name = 'ColumnName';
```

---

**MySQL**

```
SELECT IS_NULLABLE
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName';
```